potential measurement errors
I am working on a dataset for a practice problem and was given a dataset containing information on food items such as kcal (kilocalories), Potassium, Protein, etc. We were asked to analyze the dataset but were not given much information about how the data was collected. One thing I noticed is that the food items include different measurements. For example, the calories for 1 slice of pizza were measured, and a 12 fluid ounce soda. My question is, can I perform analysis on the kilo calories, since the amount of calories are measured in the same units, or should I find a common unit to minimize introducing potential errors? The issue I am having is that for some food items, such as the pizza, I am not given a measurement in ounces, so it would be hard to find a common unit. I was thinking of using a Poisson model using the count of kilo calories as a response.

Is there such a thing as a standardized "slice of pizza"? Probably not... I would think that a slice in N-Y, is not the same as in Chicago? And it certainly is not the same as in Napoli (where they do not sell it by the slice, except maybe to tourists). So if you can not be sure that "all slices were created equal", then the measurements are pretty meaningless. But if all the measurements come from pizza joints in N-Y, then the sizes are probably very similar in size (which you do not know, but so what?), and therefore you can go ahead with your analysis w/o any worry.
